# MongoDB Map-Reduce: One document that needs to be incorporated into all others matching a condition?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Not even sure of the correct terminology to use to ask this question, but here we go.

I have a collection upon which I'm using MapReduce to perform an aggregation task. I can't use the Aggregation Pipeline because I need to execute custom code while reducing.

This is slightly simplified in order to make the question clearer.

- I have a collection where each document contains a location (i.e., a grid cell ID) and a slice of time (signified by a timestamp at the start of that time slice), and contains information such as "number of cars", etc; there can be thousands of these documents per location, and can be several per slice of time as well.
- In addition, for each location there can be documents where the "slice of time" property is null. This contains information about static features and so on: i.e., data that doesn't have a timestamp associated with it.

What I want to do is to run a map-reduce process where the output documents are keyed by the location ID and slice of time, and, crucially, I am able to incorporate the untimed data with the timed data.

Here is some sample input (very simplified in terms of the data, but the `cell_id` and `timeslice` values are exactly what I have to work with):

```
[
  {
    "cell_id": 100,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 5,
    "num_residential_units": null,
    "num_commercial_units": null
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 100,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 4,
    "num_residential_units": null,
    "num_commercial_units": null
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 100,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 1,
    "num_residential_units": null,
    "num_commercial_units": null
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 100,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 7,
    "num_residential_units": null,
    "num_commercial_units": null
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 100,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 2,
    "num_residential_units": null,
    "num_commercial_units": null
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 100,
    "timeslice": null,
    "num_vehicles": null,
    "num_residential_units": 30,
    "num_commercial_units": 12
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 101,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 5,
    "num_residential_units": null,
    "num_commercial_units": null
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 101,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 1,
    "num_residential_units": null,
    "num_commercial_units": null
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 101,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 2,
    "num_residential_units": null,
    "num_commercial_units": null
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 101,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 1,
    "num_residential_units": null,
    "num_commercial_units": null
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 101,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 0,
    "num_residential_units": null,
    "num_commercial_units": null
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 101,
    "timeslice": null,
    "num_vehicles": null,
    "num_residential_units": 8,
    "num_commercial_units": 1
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 100,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 10,
    "num_residential_units": 30,
    "num_commercial_units": 12
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 100,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 9,
    "num_residential_units": 30,
    "num_commercial_units": 12
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 101,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 5,
    "num_residential_units": 8,
    "num_commercial_units": 1
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 101,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 4,
    "num_residential_units": 8,
    "num_commercial_units": 1
  }
]
```

...and the output I'd want that input to produce (I didn't split it into `_id` and `value`, but essentially the `cell_id` and `timeslice` would be the `_id`:

```
[
  {
    "cell_id": 100,
    "timeslice": null,
    "num_vehicles": null,
    "num_residential_units": 30,
    "num_commercial_units": 12
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 100,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 10,
    "num_residential_units": 30,
    "num_commercial_units": 12
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 100,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 9,
    "num_residential_units": 30,
    "num_commercial_units": 12
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 101,
    "timeslice": null,
    "num_vehicles": null,
    "num_residential_units": 8,
    "num_commercial_units": 1
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 101,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 5,
    "num_residential_units": 8,
    "num_commercial_units": 1
  },
  {
    "cell_id": 101,
    "timeslice": "2019-03-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    "num_vehicles": 4,
    "num_residential_units": 8,
    "num_commercial_units": 1
  }
]
```

If the Emit stage keys the emitted documents by location and time, then I have all the timed data making it into the reduce function properly, and I have the untimed data being reduced on its own... but I need to somehow also incorporate that untimed data into every single reduced timed data document. Is there some way to do this in the Finalize stage, or is there some clever way of setting up the keys...? I'm stumped. Frankly it doesn't matter to me if the solution even involves map-reduce, but it has to be efficient at large scale on limited hardware.

Comment: If you could add sample input documents, expected result and any code to back up your post that would be really helpful.

Comment: @user2683814 done!

Comment: Would an approach of map-reducing the time-based documents to a separate collection and then using an aggregation pipeline to join back to the untimed info work? Or do you need the untimed info for the reduce step?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

Below query will grab not null timestamp rows followed by group to get the aggregated values. After you have the aggregated doc you will join back to the same collection to pull in the untimed row.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"timeslice":{"$ne":null}}},
  {"$group":{
      "_id":{"cell_id":"$cell_id","timeslice":"$timeslice"},
      "num_vehicles":{"$sum":"$num_vehicles"}
  }},
  {"$lookup":{
     "from":"collection",
     "localField":"_id.cell_id",
     "foreignField":"cell_id",
     "as":"untimed_doc"
   }},
  {"$unwind":"$untimed_doc"},
  {"$match":{"untimed_doc.timeslice":{"$eq":null}}}
])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as mentioned in the question I need to execute some custom code during the Reduce stage; that code can't be translated into aggregation pipeline operators, so the aggregation pipeline (on its own, at least) won't work.

Comment: Sorry I may have misunderstood the last part of your post to think that you were okay without map reduce.

Comment: Ah -- yes, I'm not wedded to map-reduce per se, but it's the only thing I've been able to think of that would possibly fit the bill. Reasonably sure the aggregation pipeline, though, won't work.

Comment: I’m afraid there is no map reduce solution for this ask. You are hitting the limitation of map reduce framework

Comment: Was worried that might be the case, but holding out hope there's some clever way to approach this I haven't considered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach which might help you to solve this problem
Assumption: Based on the data you have provided looks like for each cellid, there is one record with null timeslice.

1. Filter your data based on null and not null timeslice values. This will give you two datasets.
2. Perform a join based on Cellid on these two datasets. This will bring together rows with non-null timeslice and row with null timeslice.
3. Finally group by the joined dataset using cellid and timeslice. You can run reduce on each group which will have the cell with null timeslice. However because this row is joined with every other row, you will have to handle the duplicates in your reduce. You can do that possibly by setting a flag that you have already accounted for row with null timeslice.

I have attached a picture here which might help you understand what I mean. Please note that for simplicity purpose, I have only shown CellId and timestamp columns.

[image]